# MAC : No available formula with the name "brew-cask"

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

Trying to install brew-cask after tapping caskroom/cask,

```
brew tap caskroom/cask
brew install brew-cask
```

But getting error,

```
$ brew install brew-cask
  Updating Homebrew...
  Error: No available formula with the name "brew-cask" 
  ==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
  Error: No previously deleted formula found. 
  ==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
  This similarly named formula was found:
  brew-cask-completion ✔
  To install it, run:
  brew install brew-cask-completion ✔
  ==> Searching taps...
  ==> Searching taps on GitHub...
  Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Tried brew cleanup, untapped caskroom/cask and reinstallation of brew-cask but no luck.

I installed, brew-cask-completion using brew install brew-cask-completion. And read somewhere brew-cask is deprecated. So what is the solution. I ignored it and installed the java open sdk. My question is, is it going to be a problem in future if I don't install it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: my vote turn you to 499, lol, thanks for your great question, I add my direct answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69876711/6877799) to better help for others

Answer (score 3):

It happens because of corrupted *core* installation, actually you will give this error for installing any packages, you should fix the with:

```
rm -fr $(brew --repo homebrew/core)
```

Then install what ever you want, for me:

```
brew intall deno
```

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling it with these commands in this order:

```
brew uninstall brew-cask
brew untap caskroom/cask
brew tap caskroom/cask
brew install brew-cask
```

Comment: I tried this uninstalling brew-cask, errror thrown Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/brew-cask

Comment: brew-cask is deprecated. Any idea what to use instead of it or some other solution?

Comment: @Rashmi ah I see. try switching to the new system with `brew uninstall --force brew-cask; brew update` and try using just `brew` rather than `brew cask`

Comment: I have installed brew-cask-completion. Any idea about it?is it a replacement to brew-cask? I will try your solution.

Comment: You mean instead of brew-cask I should try brew. Then it would be brew install brew. Isn't it weird command? Already tried brew uninstall --force brew-cask; no luck.

Comment: what script are you going to use with brew-cask i mean? like, installing java you can use `brew cask install java` then the new way would be `brew install java`

Comment: Yeah all this for openjdk. I installed it and it got install also. But my concern is, will failed to install brew-cask create any problem in future?

Comment: ah. no i think if you uninstall it that warning should go away